# VBA Copied sheet formula references original sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a workbook and I am trying to have it so that if a certain sheet in the active workbook is accidentally deleted, it will pull the deleted sheet from a copy of the original file in a different file location.

My issue is that when it copies the sheet, the formulas reference the file on the server (EX: SUM([BACKUP]Sheet1!C13:G13) instead of the data on the active workbook.

Here is my code. I tried doing Paste special but I couldn't get it to work.

```
Const fromFile = "G:\BACKUPWORKBOOK"
Sub COPYPASTE()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim srcBook As Workbook
    Set srcBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(fromFile, _
        UpdateLinks:=False, _
        ReadOnly:=True, _
        AddToMRU:=False)



        srcBook.Sheets("SheetIWantToCopy").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        srcBook.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Is there anyway to allow it to copy the formulas but not reference the original document?

Comment: Try inserting a new sheet and copying the range of "SheetIWantToCopy", instead of copying the entire sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is doing exactly what it is being asked to do, copying, and therefore referential integrity is maintained...

You need to just remove the reference text, you could do a batch find and replace on that sheet.

Or, you could just make the copy hidden within the Excel workbook by using Right Click and hide it... that way nobody will know it is there and you can use that as a restore and all it's references are intact... just copy that, you can even use VBA to do it.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me! I now have it where the VBA hides the sheet or shows the sheet depending on what option I select. Thank you!